# Syntax error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my code written in Ruby:

```
class Prgram
  def method(i)
    a = [] 
    b = []
    puts "enter numbering to the index from 0 to till #{i-1}"
    for k in 0..i-1
      a = gets
    end
    puts "enter #{i} titles of the index  numbers "
    for l in 0..i-1
      b = gets
    end
    linewidth = 40
    for m in 0..i-1
      puts "#{a[m].ljust (lineWidth/2) + b[m].rjust (lineWidth/2)}"
    end
  end
end
obj = Program.new
puts "enter how many index values yopu want to print"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
obj.method(n)
```

I've gotten this error:

```
Index.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting tSTRING_DEND
      puts "#{a[m].ljust (lineWidth/2) + b[m].rjust (lineWidth/2)}"
```

I don't know what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: ljust arraange the value in left side, rjust arrange the value in righr side @uDaY

Comment: `a = gets` should be `a << gets` if you want to build an array, otherwise you're just overwriting `a` each time.

Comment: i think that questions should be specific so that they are searchable in the future. that is one of the benefits of stack overflow - a library of answers.

Answer (score 2):

Fix is -

```
 puts "#{a[m].ljust(lineWidth/2) + b[m].rjust(lineWidth/2)}"
```

You can call a method as

```
 # good
 obj.meth 1 
 # good  
 obj.meth(1) 
 # Never put a space between a method name and the opening parenthesis. It is bad
 # style.
 obj.meth (1)
```

One more typo -

```
class Prgram
```

should be

```
class Program
```